# .htaccess redirect non existing pages based on index.php page with wildcard and something after it to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

Please help, some website is arbitrarily adding dynamic query strings to my home page.

For example my home page is www.mysite.com/index.php and they link to many links like this:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-something-something
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-other
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=some-other-thing
```

And those links are opening on my site, content of page are the same for every page, just like my original www.mysite.com/index.php

There are few hundreds of that links pointing to my site. So how I can redirect this:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-something-something
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-other
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=some-other-thing
...
```

to

`www.mysite.com/index.php` or just to `www.mysite.com/`

This what I tried so far in my .htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^index.php?a= http://www.www.example-ste.com/
RewriteRule ^/index.php?a=(.*) http://www.example-ste.com/
```

But still pages are opening on site.

---

**Another similar question.**

How to redirect pages ending with "**?pagewanted=all**" to the same page but with out that **"?pagewanted=all"**

For example I need to redirect page:

**www.mysite.com/something-something/something.html?pagewanted=all**

to

**www.mysite.com/something-something/something.html**

---

Hello.

I just noticed something. I needed URL redirection rule which will redirect pages like:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-something-something
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-other
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=some-other-thing
```

to home page of site, root. And you gave me this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the query string has an a parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a= [NC]
#Redirect and remove query string parameters
RewriteRule .*  http://www.mysite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

And I must say it works fine, it does that, but I just noticed that it somehow blocks or redirect all links containing `?a=` for example on some temporary pages I have links like:

```
i.php?a=something-something-something
```

So, can you adopt code just for pages based on index.php like:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?a=something-something-something
```

and not for links with:

```
i.php?a=something-something-something
```

If I am right it works on all links with "`a=`" but I need just for "`index.php?a=`"

Comment: Does anyone has any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the folloginw to the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the query string has an a parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a= [NC]
#Redirect and remove query string parameters
RewriteRule .*  http://www.mysite.com/? [R=301,L]

#if the query string has a pagewanted parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pagewanted=all [NC]
#Redirect and remove query string parameters for html pages
RewriteRule (.+\.html)  http://www.mysite.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Edit.
Added rule to remove  `pagewanted=all`

Comment: If it works then pls mark the answer as accepted by clicking tick mark on LHS of the answer.