# How to remove certain strings in a non-existing URL and redirect it to another URL using .htaccess in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

This is my first question here in stackoverflow. This website really helped me a lot in terms of web development using Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, javascript, HTML, JQuery and a lot more in the world of web development. Thanks and many thanks!

I've also searched this site which is also related to the title of this question but honestly, none of them answers directly my question. I really was struggling for days trying to work this one out but I never really got the correct solution.

So here is my problem. **I've been trying to redirect these non-existing URL's in my Joomla site using `.htaccess` but I couldn't make it right.** Can any of you suggest how should this be done in the `.htaccess`?

> www.mysite.com/index.php/component/content/37-2009-10-15-19-28-33?format=feed&type=rss

should redirect to

> www.mysite.com/index.php/component/content

---

> www.mysite.com/index.php/paving-horizontal-concrete/park/34?format=feed&type=atom

should redirect to

> www.mysite.com/index.php/paving-horizontal-concrete/park

---

> www.mysite.com/index.php/component/content/56?layout=blog&format=feed&type=rss

should redirect to

> www.mysite.com/index.php/component/content/

---

I tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535587/htaccess-redirect-non-existing-pages-based-on-index-php-page-with-wildcard-and) but still unsuccessful.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: In short, it seems you want to remove the last string (segment path) from the incoming URL. Is that right?

Comment: could you post your current htaccess rules?

Comment: Yes @faa you are right!

Comment: This is what I've got so far @PaoloStefan..  `RewriteEngine On`  `RewriteRule ^index.php/paving-horizontal-concrete/traffic-island/35?format=feed&type=rss$ /index.php/paving-horizontal-concrete/traffic-island [R=301,L]`

Comment: The example you posted doesn't work because `RewriteRule` matches against the path part of your URL **without** the query string. If you want to extract parts of the query string, you have to use a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...`. Also, if you force an external redirect using the R flag, you won't be able to recover the parts of the URL you discarded with your rule. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @nwellnhof . So what can you suggest on how to remove the last string (segment path) from the incoming URL just what faa pointed earlier in this thread? I really am not sure how to that. Can you help me how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the final part of the URL path and use a permanent external redirect, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index\.php/[^/]+/[^/]+)/ $1 [R=301,L]
```

But as i noted in my comment, you won't be able to recover the final part or the query string later.

**Edit:** If you want to keep the query string, simply add the `[QSA]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/[^/]+/[^/]+)/ $1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Alternatively, you can use an internal redirect by removing the `[R]` flag. Then you'll find the original URL in environment variables `REQUEST_URI` (including the query string) or `REDIRECT_URL` (excluding the query string).

Comment: If I want to recover the query string later, will I be able to achieve it when I remove the `R=301`?

Comment: Thank you very much @nwellnhof! It solved the problem! I'm glad you are there to help me out. Thanks again! :). I wanted to vote one for your answer but I still can't vote because I am a newbie here.

Comment: @norvin1107 You should be able to accept my answer without any reputation by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.