# Redirect Specific non-existing URL to an existing

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a simple need to redirect:

`mypage.com/myurl` (which doesn't not exist; meening that returns a 404 error)

To

`mypage.com/newurl/myurl` (which is an exitsing page with content).

I saw a tons of forum post about this, but didn't find an awnser. I tried lot of thinks but with internal server error, infinitive loops etc.

Please note that I have a www to non www permanent redirect, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mypage\.si [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mypage.si/$1 [L,R=301]
```

UPDATE:

I will be specific:

This URL doesn't exist:  http://domodom.si/sl/nepremicnine

and needs to be redirected here: http://domodom.si/sl/nepremicnine/nepremicnine-ponudba

Hope this will offer more insights about the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming mod_rewrite

RedirectPermanent /myurl/ mypage.com/newurl/myurl

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newurl/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try implementing the answer of nwellnhof in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767548/how-to-remove-certain-strings-in-a-non-existing-url-and-redirect-it-to-another-u).. it worked for me..